# Is it possible to create a connection between raised button and texfield?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Is it possible to create a connection between raised button and texfield?
I want to make a QuizApp where you enter the answer in the textfield and when you press the button that is checked by an If, else method, if what is entered in the textfield is correct. How can I do that ?

```
Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[

                   TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText:"put in the correct answer", 
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                      ),
                      key: _formKey,
                      autovalidate: true,
                      validator: (String value){
                        if (value.contains("test") ){
                        return "Gebe mehr ein";
                        }else{
                        return null;}
                      }
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                            debugPrint("Alles richtig gemacht.");
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    )


              ],)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give onSaved method to your TextFormField.

```
TextFormField(
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.lock),
    labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("password"),
  ),
  onSaved: (String val) {
    _password = val;
  },
  validator: (val) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(validatePassword(val));
  },
),
```

And if your form validates, you can save your form. So when you save your form, all the onSaved() methods will be invoked in the descendant widgets of form widget, which will basically save the value in a variable in the above example.

Or you can give TextEditingController to your TextFormField Widget.

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
```

Add a listener to it in `initState` method.

```
_controller.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    _amount = _controller.text;
  });
});
```

and dispose the controller in `dispose` method.

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: I get a lot of error. Can you help me? I get by AppLocalizations an error it says "Undefined name 'AppLocalizations'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dart(undefined_identifier)". and by "Undefined name 'FontAwesomeIcons'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name." and by validatePassword and by _controller

Comment: Yeah because I've copied from my project. Sorry for the confusion, AppLocalizations is about localization. Just remove that and put any string you want there. I'm also using FontAwesome icons. You can just use any icon, Icons.add for example or just remove prefixIcon property, it just puts an icon in front of textfield box. I've also suggest that you to understand the concept about "onSaved" and "TextEditingController", rather than simply copying and pasting.